# Conjugate gradient inversion in Armadillo?

Tags: sparse-matrix, armadillo

I can't find a conjugate gradient inversion in Armadillo or that works with Armadillo.  CG is very useful for inversion of a sparse matrix and for large matrix inversion where you only need the pseudo-inverse.  (Armadillo pinv() uses SVD, which is expensive.....)

Does this not exist?  Is there interest in CG based pinv() for dense and sparse matrices?

Comment: Is that at all related to the divide and conquer method they include as an option to pinv?  The sparse matrix solvers are relatively limited compared to dense in armadillo it seems.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the D&C method is different from Conjugate Gradient.  While the two algorithms share some abstract principals, they operate differently.  The D&C is good for getting all the eigenvectors, the Conjugate Gradient doesn't bother with getting eigenvectors and doesn't bother with the small singular values.   CG is blazingly fast if only inverting the top ~5% of the singular values, which is often all you want with large matrices.

Comment: If you're not wedded to Armadillo, Eigen may be a useful alternative? https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html